Further explain natural language explanation for statements deduced from master theorem for solving recurrences
This content is taken from from Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein, Introduction to Algorithms, The MIT Press, 2022, Chapter 4.
Given the following recurrence for $a \gt 0 \text{ and } b \gt 1$,
$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
\theta(1) & \text{if } 0 \leq n \lt 1 \\ 
a \cdot T \left( n/b \right) + f \left( n \right) & \text{if } n \geq 1
\end{cases}$$
we have a solution
$$
T(n) = \theta \left( n^{log_b^a} \right) + \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor log_b^n \rfloor} a^j \cdot f \left( \frac{n}{b^j} \right)
$$
For such recurrence, master theorem has following cases stated mathematically.

If there exists a constant $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $f(n) = O\left( n^{log_b^{a-\epsilon}} \right) $, then $T(n) = \theta \left( n^{log_b^a} \right)$

If there exists a constant $k \geq 0$ such that $f(n) = \theta\left( n^{log_b^a} \cdot log_2^k(n) \right) $, then $T(n) = \theta \left( n^{log_b^a} \cdot log_2^{k+1}(n) \right)$

If there exists a constant $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $f(n) = \Omega\left( n^{log_b^{a+\epsilon}} \right) $, and if $f(n)$ additionally satisfies the regularity condition $a \cdot f(n/b) \leq c\cdot f(n)$ for some constant $c < 1$ and all sufficiently large $n$, then $T(n) = \theta \left(f(n) \right)$


I am able to deduce the given solution by expanding the given recurrence so no problems there. I would like a better explanation of the following informal statements (Case 1 - 3).
Case 1: The costs increase geometrically from the root to the leaves, growing by
a constant factor with each level.
Case 2: The costs depend on the value of k in the theorem. With $k = 0$, the costs
are equal for each level; with $k = 1$, the costs grow linearly from the leaves to
the root; with $k = 2$, the growth is quadratic; and in general, the costs grow
polynomially in k.
Case 3: The costs decrease geometrically from the root to the leaves, shrinking
by a constant factor with each level.
My attempt at understanding (using recursion tree visualization):
I know that total cost at topmost root level compared to total cost at leaf level can be lower or higher by a factor of $n$ raised to some positive power for cases 1 and 3 respectively but what is meant by "geometrically"?
Also, I don't truly understand the underlying implication of regularity condition imposed or rationale behind it for case 3. It is stated that total cost of all internal nodes at level, say level $y$, 1 level below, say level $z$, should be less than or equal to total cost of internal nodes at level $z$. So, the cost of dividing problems and rejoining solutions at we move from root level to leaf level cannot be more than cost at topmost root. This makes some sense to me but I feel that my understanding is still bit vague.
I am total loss for case 2, I don't understand what is meant by linear, quadratic or polynomial growth in k. It is also states elsewhere in the text that cost of each level stays about the same for case 2 which is also not apparent to me.

